# Showing that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, using the mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The following exercise is again about the Mean Value Theorem :)

> Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and differentiable on $(0,1)$.
>   Assume that $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f'(x)= \lambda.$$
>
> Show that $f$ is differentiable (from the right) at $0$ and that $f'(0)=\lambda$.
>
> **Hint**: Mean Value Theorem.

What exactly is 'differentiable from the right'? Do I have to show that the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right side exists? How can I do that?

How can I use the Mean Value Theorem to show that the derivative on $0$ equals $\lambda$?

Mean Value Theorem: If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $ [a,b] $ and differentiable on $ (a,b)$, then there exists a point $ c \in (a,b)$ where

$$ f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

Comment: What you have is incorrect. Look here for a contradiction. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157675/show-that-f-is-not-continuous-at-0-for-the-following-function/157680#157680

Comment: "Do I have to show that the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right side exists?" No, that is given to you in the assumption.

Comment: @EdGorcenski $lim f'(x) = \lambda$, but I have to show that $f$ is differentiable from the right at 0. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Marvis What exactly is incorrect? This is a homework assignment

Comment: "$f$ is differentiable from the right at $0$" means that $$\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}h$$ exists. Use the mean value theorem to rewrite $f(h)-f(0)$.

Comment: The link that Marvis posted deals with another thing, namely that $f'(0)$ can exist, even if $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Hempo Look at the formal definition of a derivative. Now, replace the limit with the limit from the right, i.e. $\lim_{x \to b} F(x) \to \lim_{x \to b^+} F(x)$.

Comment: @mrf Thanks for pointing it out. I understand it now from the MVT though it is taking time to sink in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiable at $\alpha$ from right means $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \alpha^+} \frac{f(x)-f(\alpha)}{x-\alpha}}$ exist. Its value is $f'_+(\alpha)$.

For your case, from MVT, for each $x>0$ exist $0<y_x<x$, s.t. $f'(y_x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$. If you take $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}}$ you get your result.

Answer (score 4):

Showing that $f$ is differentiable from the right at $0$ means showing the existence of $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$ (this of course generalizes to numbers other than $0$). In particular (in this case), that this limit is equal to $\lambda$.

For a rigorous (and fairly brief) proof, take any $\epsilon>0$. There is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f'(x)-\lambda|<\epsilon$ for all $0<x<\delta$. (Why?) Fix any $0<x<\delta$, and consider the expression $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}-\lambda\right|.$$ What does MVT let us do with the difference quotient in the expression? Given our choice of $\delta$ and of $x$, how does our expression then compare to $\epsilon$? Since we chose our $0<x<\delta$ arbitrarily, what does that mean, by definition?

Comment: Can I say $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f'(x)=\lambda \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lambda \Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0^+} \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lambda \Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0^+}  \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lambda \Rightarrow f'(0^+)=\lambda$ ? any logical error?

Comment: @Messi, there are a few issues. The biggest one is that you have to justify that you can interchange the order of the limits with respect to $h$ and $x,$ as it isn't always possible without changing the value. For another, I think you meant $f'(0)=\lambda,$ since $0^+$ isn't a number.

Comment: Of course I mean $f'(0)=\lambda$, and whats wrong with the interchange of limits as the existence of limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},~0<x<1$, and continuity of $f$ are been presupposed? more specifically, if $g(x,h)$ is continuous w.r.t $x$ and has limit at $h \to 0^+$, I can interchange the limit, right? thanks in advance.

Comment: @MessiLio, unfortunately, not in general. Consider the function $$g(x,h)=2^{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{h}}.$$ Here are some key facts. (1) This is continuous with respect to $x$ on $(0,1)$ for any non-zero $h$. (2) For any $x\in(0,1)$ $$\lim_{h\searrow 0}g(x,h)=0.$$ (3) $$\lim_{x\searrow 0}\lim_{h\searrow 0}g(x,h)=0.$$ (4) $$\lim_{h\searrow 0}\lim_{x\searrow 0}g(x,h)=\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Being differentiable at $0$ from the right means $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-\alpha}}$ exist. Its value is $f'_+(0)$.

From the Mean Value Theorem, for each $x>0$ there exists a $y$ with $0<y<x$,  such that $$f'(y)=\lambda=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

This implies that:$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}} f'(y) = \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}}  \lambda= \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+}}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'_+(0) = \lambda$$

Is this a good proof? Thanks for your help all :-)

Comment: It's good (though you've got an $\alpha$ in one of the denominators, when you should have a $0$). Depending on your professor, though (or depending on the axioms and theorems you have to work with), you might need something a bit more rigorous.